# checking coma's validity in a given string/number in php

Tags: php, format, numbers

So In case if the user types in 1,000.00, this is a valid number. what if the user types in 1,0,000,00.0000,0 
You see theres multiple errors in here where you a value cannot be 1,0... or 000,00 because it has to be at least 3 numbers after the comma. To further extend it, after the dot in a number you cannot have a comma.

$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];

```
if (preg_match('/0/',$keyword) ||preg_match('/1/',$keyword) ||preg_match('/2/',$keyword)||preg_match('/3/',$keyword) ||preg_match('/4/',$keyword) || preg_match('/5/',$keyword) || preg_match('/6/',$keyword) || preg_match('/7/',$keyword) ||preg_match('/8/',$keyword) ||preg_match('/9/',$keyword) ||preg_match('/-/',$keyword) ||preg_match('/+/',$keyword) || preg_match('/,/',$keyword) ) {
$keywordtest = $keyword;
if ($keyword[0] == '+' || $keyword[0] == '-')
{
    $keywordtest = substr_replace($keyword, '1', 0, 1);
    echo $keywordtest;
    }
if (preg_match('/,/',$keyword))
{
$x = 0;
while(true)
{
$findme   = ',';
$pos = strpos($keyword, $findme);
if ($pos !== false) 
    {
    $posArray[x] = $pos;
    $x = x + 1;
    if (x == 10)
    break;
    }   

}

$numberCheck = posArray[x-1];
if (is_numeric($numberCheck))
{
}
else 
{
echo "false '{$keyword}' is not numeric", PHP_EOL;
return 0;
}

$numberCheck = posArray[x+1];
if (is_numeric($numberCheck))
{
}
else 
{
echo "false '{$keyword}' is not numeric", PHP_EOL;
return 0;
}

$numberCheck = posArray[x+2];
if (is_numeric($numberCheck))
{
}
else 
{
echo "false '{$keyword}' is not numeric", PHP_EOL;
return 0;
}

$numberCheck = posArray[x+3];
if (is_numeric($numberCheck))
{
}
else 
{
echo "false '{$keyword}' is not numeric", PHP_EOL;
return 0;
}

}    



       test_numeric($keywordtest,$keyword);
       return 0;
}

else
    {

        echo "false '{$keyword}' is not numeric", PHP_EOL;

}
function test_numeric($keywordtest,$keyword)
{
    if (is_numeric($keywordtest)){

    echo "true '{$keyword}' is numeric", PHP_EOL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

?>

Comment: What i have done here is that, i take the + and - and covert them into numbers and pass it to the is_numeric function and return the results as true or false.

However how would i test if the number before and after the comma is a valid number. I tried putting the commas location and check if the numbers before and after are valid numbers, however i think this is the least efficient way of doing it, and this code doesn't work

Comment: Could you please format your code properly?

Comment: Something wrong with the format? I really just need to know how to work the commas. To take in the a string and to check it if it's a valid number

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) in combination with the FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT [filter type](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and the FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND flag.

Then it is really straightforward:

```
// $val == 100000
$val = filter_var('100,000.00', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, array('flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND));

// $val == -100000
$val = filter_var('-100,000.00', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, array('flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND));

// $val === false (invalid)
$val = filter_var('100,000.00,00', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, array('flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND));
```

Comment: What other numbers?

Comment: say if they put 203,221,121.12 like literally any possible number

Comment: Well, yes. As long as it can be represented by PHP's float.